# download entire website with wget

Tags: wget

I want to download the entire wikipedia to have an offline copy, I try using that command:

```
wget --recursive --domains --convert-links --no-clobber https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/
```

But it download only the first page. How can I use it?

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: You can download an offline wikipedia reader (e.g. [Aard](http://aarddict.org/index.html)) and the [corresponding dictionary](https://github.com/itkach/slob/wiki/Dictionaries#italian).

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia’s [`robots.txt`](https://it.wikipedia.org/robots.txt) excludes `wget`:

```
#
# Sorry, wget in its recursive mode is a frequent problem.
# Please read the man page and use it properly; there is a
# --wait option you can use to set the delay between hits,
# for instance.
#
User-agent: wget
Disallow: /
```

Please follow their advice. In particular, you probably shouldn’t download Wikipedia using a tool such as `wget`, but use [their offline database download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) instead.